# The purge error with the customize reconfigured debian package

Tags: linux, debian

I try to build a debian package which to replace the lirc initial script

I have been referenced [Building a preconfigured debian package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13253144/building-a-preconfigured-debian-package?answertab=active#tab-top), [How to use dpkg-divert to temporarily remove/replace symlink when package is installed?](https://serverfault.com/questions/279331/how-to-use-dpkg-divert-to-temporarily-remove-replace-symlink-when-package-is-ins) and [Debian Policy Manual Appendix G](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ap-pkg-diversions.html)

But it has the problem with removes the package.

Here is the install prompt and it can be installed successfully

Setting up mylirctest (0.0.1) ...

```
Configuration file '/etc/init.d/lirc'
==> Deleted (by you or by a script) since installation.
==> Package distributor has shipped an updated version.
What would you like to do about it ?  Your options are:
Y or I  : install the package maintainer's version
N or O  : keep your currently-installed version
  D     : show the differences between the versions
  Z     : start a shell to examine the situation
The default action is to keep your current version.
*** lirc (Y/I/N/O/D/Z) [default=N] ? Y
Installing new version of config file /etc/init.d/lirc ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-16) ...
```

There is the problem when progress my package

```
(Reading database ... 148259 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing mylirctest (0.0.1) ...
Removing 'diversion of /etc/init.d/lirc to /etc/init.d/lirc.disable by      mylirctest'
dpkg-divert: error: rename involves overwriting `/etc/init.d/lirc' with
different file `/etc/init.d/lirc.disable', not allowed
dpkg: error processing package hdstation (--purge):
subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
mylirctest
```

Here is my preinst file:

```
#/bin/sh
set -e
dpkg-divert --package mylirctest --add --rename --divert /etc/init.d/lirc.disable /etc/init.d/lirc
```

The postrm

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e
dpkg-divert --package mylirctest --remove --rename --divert /etc/init.d/lirc.disable /etc/init.d/lirc
```

Is there any wrong with my postrm?
And How can I disable the prompt message when install my deb package?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's a year old question, but I've faced the same issue and fixed it, so here is the answer in case someone need it:

To properly restore the file using dpkg-divert in postrm you have to delete current file first, like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e
rm /etc/init.d/lirc
dpkg-divert --package mylirctest --remove --rename --divert /etc/init.d/lirc.disable /etc/init.d/lirc
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a major update available in the Debian experimental channel. It's a breaking update with completely new configuration. That said, the old lirc packaging bug exposed here should be fixed in the updated package (0.9.4b)